# Heroku deployment failing - reactjs app/webpack?

Tags: reactjs, logging, heroku, deployment

I have built a simple react app, which for some reason, fails when I deploy to heroku...  The build appears to be successful, but my content doesn't show/there's an error.

When I check my heroku logs, here's what i get.  But I'm not sure exactly, what's the issue...:

Here's my github too, so you can see the code/web pack details etc:

https://github.com/ReenaVerma/GOLIN-TEST

```
    ➜  GOLIN-TEST git:(master) ✗ heroku logs
    2018-05-29T09:54:48.686630+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2018-05-29T09:54:48.663859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2018-05-29T13:17:50.600366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2018-05-29T13:17:50.344394+00:00 app[api]: Set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION config vars by user reena_verma@hotmail.com
    2018-05-29T13:17:50.344394+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user reena_verma@hotmail.com
    2018-05-29T13:17:52.783893+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.871172+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.787907+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.787925+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-webpack-setup@1.0.0 start /app
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.787927+00:00 app[web.1]: > webpack-dev-server
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.787928+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.796872+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.801464+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.801869+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.802095+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.802332+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.803493+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! react-webpack-setup@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.803676+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.803895+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.804114+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the react- webpack-setup@1.0.0 start script.
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.804270+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.814559+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.814687+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.814750+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-05-29T13_17_54_805Z-debug.log
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.886992+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2018-05-29T13:17:54.889252+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2018-05-29T13:17:57.774256+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.396955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.367329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.252378+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.252404+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-webpack-setup@1.0.0 start /app
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.252406+00:00 app[web.1]: > webpack-dev-server
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.252407+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.265715+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.271867+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.272232+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.272506+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.272828+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.274432+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! react-webpack-setup@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.274665+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.275002+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.275263+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the react-webpack-setup@1.0.0 start script.
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.275520+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.286124+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.286257+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-05-29T13_18_00_277Z-debug.log
    2018-05-29T13:18:00.285904+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-05-29T13:19:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user reena_verma@hotmail.com
    2018-05-29T13:20:10.047861+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2018-05-29T13:20:09.687189+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user 
    reena_verma@hotmail.com
2018-05-29T13:20:09.687189+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0ccd4f16 by user 
    reena_verma@hotmail.com
    2018-05-29T13:20:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2018-05-29T13:20:16.565903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
     2018-05-29T13:20:18.676323+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-05-29T13:20:18.676361+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-webpack-setup@1.0.0 start /app
    2018-05-29T13:20:18.676363+00:00 app[web.1]: > webpack-dev-server
    2018-05-29T13:20:18.676364+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-05-29T13:20:20.167148+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack output is served from /
    2018-05-29T13:20:20.167212+00:00 app[web.1]: Content not from webpack is served from src
    2018-05-29T13:20:20.222367+00:00 app[web.1]: Unable to open browser. If you are running in a headless environment, please do not use the open flag.
    2018-05-29T13:20:20.167258+00:00 app[web.1]: 404s will fallback to /index.html
    2018-05-29T13:20:20.166932+00:00 app[web.1]: Project is running at http://localhost:8000/
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809465+00:00 app[web.1]: Hash: 13feeba3b007d3242808
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809481+00:00 app[web.1]: Version: webpack 3.11.0
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809483+00:00 app[web.1]: Time: 3726ms
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809486+00:00 app[web.1]: Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809487+00:00 app[web.1]: app.js    1.11 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809489+00:00 app[web.1]: index.html  204 bytes          [emitted]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809491+00:00 app[web.1]: assets/scss/main.scss  301 bytes          [emitted]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809492+00:00 app[web.1]: assets/scss/components/body.scss  198 bytes          [emitted]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809494+00:00 app[web.1]: assets/scss/components/form.scss    1.47 kB          [emitted]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809495+00:00 app[web.1]: assets/scss/components/progress-bar.scss  255 bytes          [emitted]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809497+00:00 app[web.1]: assets/scss/components/typography.scss   92 bytes          [emitted]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809499+00:00 app[web.1]: assets/.gitkeep    0 bytes          [emitted]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809501+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809502+00:00 app[web.1]: [5] (webpack)/hot/log.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809504+00:00 app[web.1]: [11] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809506+00:00 app[web.1]: [20] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/app.js 52 bytes {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809507+00:00 app[web.1]: [21] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 7.93 kB {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809508+00:00 app[web.1]: [22] ./node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809510+00:00 app[web.1]: [32] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.08 kB {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809511+00:00 app[web.1]: [34] (webpack)-dev- 
 server/client/overlay.js 3.67 kB {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809512+00:00 app[web.1]: [39] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809513+00:00 app[web.1]: [41] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.61 kB {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809514+00:00 app[web.1]: [42] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.31 kB {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809516+00:00 app[web.1]: [43] ./src/app.js 5.48 kB {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809517+00:00 app[web.1]: [47] ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 1.36 kB {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809518+00:00 app[web.1]: [56] ./src/components/ProgressBar.js 835 bytes {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809519+00:00 app[web.1]: [60] ./src/components/Form.js 6.03 kB {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809520+00:00 app[web.1]: + 46 hidden modules
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809522+00:00 app[web.1]: Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809523+00:00 app[web.1]: 1 asset
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809525+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 553 bytes {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809526+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809527+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809528+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
    2018-05-29T13:20:23.809534+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack: Compiled successfully.
    2018-05-29T13:21:17.346647+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2018-05-29T13:21:17.217415+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
   2018-05-29T13:21:17.217544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
    2018-05-29T13:21:17.327732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Comment: are you going to launch webpack-dev-server on heroku? it's not supposed to be production server, right?

Comment: did you have a chance to check out this build pack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack. seems relevant.

Comment: if you don't plan any backend, I'd suggest netlify, it's very straightforward, you just point to the repo, set few config parameters and it's up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are using `webpack-dev-server` to run your project. This package is defined under devDependencies in your [package.json](https://github.com/ReenaVerma/GOLIN-TEST/blob/master/package.json#L27), which means when you deploy on heroku, it (heroku) will run build for production which means all devDependencies will not be included and hence the error

> sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found

So if you really, really want to run a dev server in a production environment, then include webpack-dev-server in the dependecies section of your package file as opposed to devDependencies.

If not, which is what I would suggest, then follow on [this](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static). It will take you through on how to prepare your environment for deploying on heroku for production.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  There's actually no back-end/server side code in this project... so I guess I don't need webpack-dev-server?

Comment: Whether or not you have a backend, the dev server is still needed to serve the bundle that webpack builds for you. But I would recommend that you use the dev server only for that; development not production. In production use the `node` executable.

Comment: ok, really sorry, i'm still a beginner to heroku deployment....  So @brandnew - what should I change/update to make this work in PROD?

Comment: Thats okay. I have attached a link in my answer that is really helpful. It is a comprehensive step by step process on how to prepare a prod env for heroku

Comment: Ok, so basically I should rebuild the app from scratch to deploy?

Comment: Not at all. You just a Procfile to tell heroku what commands to run to get your project onboard. You also need a file called static.json for specifying the build folder and other metadata that heroku may require to correctly serve your project. So its just additional info, not rebuilding the whole project. You prolly wont even need to touch your source code.

Comment: ok thank you.  I'll have a go and try that later this evening.... I could be blind... but i didnt see a profile mentioned in the link... just static.json... :p . thank you